# Unexpected field access control behaviour in KeystoneJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I am attempting to apply field level access logic in KeystoneJS, as per [these instructions](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/access-control/#field-level-access-control).

The following hides a field `fieldName` from the admin UI:

```
fieldName: {
  type: Text,
  access: {
    read: false,
    update: false,
    create: false
  },
},
```

But the field is **not** hidden from the admin UI if I use an [imperative approach](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/access-control/#shorthand-imperative-boolean-1). See below, which I would expect to produce the same result as the static approach above:

```
fieldName: {
  type: Text,
  access: {
    read: ({ authentication: { item, listKey } }) => {
      return false;
    },
    update: ({ authentication: { item, listKey } }) => {
      return false;
    },
    create: ({ authentication: { item, listKey } }) => {
      return false;
    }
  },
},
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imperative approach uses a function which can not be transferred to the client side.

Keystone uses maybe `true` `false` value for this. this means `!!(() => {})` becomes true when generating admin ui metadata for fields in list.

there is a note in the section ["Granular Imperative Boolean"](https://www.keystonejs.com/api/access-control#granular-imperative-boolean-1) which explains that these fields indeed gets included in graphql and ui but are excluded during execution.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Gautam - I'll explore other approaches. Looking forward to the new admin UI updates! https://www.keystonejs.com/blog/roadmap-update